# SystemUpdate() causes "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."

Tags: permissions, csom, azure-functions

I need to use ".SystemUpdate()" inside Azure Function.
I'm getting the token using Resource Owner Password Credentials flow and:

1. After performing SystemUpdate I got "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.".
2. The account has a Site Collection admin permission,
3. The same account can perform SystemUpdate from PowerShell,
4. Ordinary Update works fine,
5. Entra/AAD App has AllSites.Write delegated permission.

I've tried also to perform SystemUpdate in the application context with Sites.Selected permission but it was executed as ordinary Update.

What should I do to make SystemUpdate work in CSOM in Azure Function? What is missing? Sites.WritAll is not an option.